# Update query keeps throwing errors

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
UPDATE qryMembersBorrows
SET [qryMembersBorrows].[DaysOver] = SUM([qryMembersBorrows].[DateReturned] - [qryMembersBorrows].[DateDue]), 
    qryMembersBorrows.OverdueFine = SUM([qryMembersBorrows].[DaysOver] * 0.93);
```

This code keeps throwing an error:

> Your query does not include the specified expression as a part of an aggregate function

Comment: You cannot use aggregation functions like that.  Sample data and desire results would help.

Comment: Why save calculated values? These calcs can be performed when needed.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel Sum() function is used to add up a range of cells. In Access Sum() function is to aggregate records, not perform arithmetic between fields.

Day is default unit for arithmetic with dates. Just do the math. Will have to repeat the elapsed time calculation in the OverdueFine calc.

```
UPDATE qryMembersBorrows 
SET DaysOver = [DateReturned]-[DateDue], OverdueFine = ([DateReturned]-[DateDue])*0.93;
```

Use DateDiff() if you want to calculate other date/time units.